# onUpgrade in sqlite external database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing a database application and I am stuck up at one place.

How to upgrade external database after adding new table in Database in android sqlite?

after updating my app I got error: No such table found in database

Answer (score 0):

You have to **Update the Version Number**

```
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
       public DBHelper(){
          super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,VersionNumber);// Change Version here
       }
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}

      //While upgrading pass new version

       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
    }
```

**Example**

[How to use onUpgrade() correctly](https://riggaroo.co.za/android-sqlite-database-use-onupgrade-correctly/)

Answer (score 0):

In SQLiteOpenHelper class

```
  public abstract void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, 
            int oldVersion, 
            int newVersion)
```

Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else it needs to upgrade to the new schema version.

Comment: is it necessary to change onUpgrade() after adding new column in table ?(it is external database)

Comment: Since its External database in class extending SQLiteAssetHelper change database version ideally it is called in Contructor.